# How to request php feature from php deveolpers

Tags: php

Is there an official way to request php feature from php deveolpers ?

What I want to ask that they allow some keyword in function call to use default value

example with current version

```
function foo(a=null, b=null){
  if(a===null) a=1;
  if(b===null) b=2;
  return a+b;
}

foo(null, 5);
```

I want it to be something like

```
function foo(a=1, b=2){
  return a+b;
}

foo(default, 5);
```

As you see it's more easier and of course will be more efficient if it implemented from the language itself

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/skipparams

Comment: so this feature has beed refused , but how can i request another feature if i had one ?

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/howto

Comment: You already have one below.

Comment: you are the first to give the url ,so i'd like to accept urs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Request For Comments](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/howto)